# Cannot get back original values of image points after calibrating camera

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

After calibrating my camera using `OpenCv`'s `calibrateCamera` method and obtaining its parameters, when I try to reproduce my original object points I get nonsensical output.
Here is my code:

```
vector<vector<cv::Point3f> >  object_points;
vector<vector<cv::Point2f> > image_points;

cv::Mat cam_mat;

cv::Mat dist_coeffs;
vector<cv::Mat> rvecs, tvecs;

std::vector<cv::Point3f> t_3d;
t_3d.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.9, -3, 57.5));
t_3d.push_back(cv::Point3f(1.45, -3, 57.5));
t_3d.push_back(cv::Point3f(2, -3, 57.5));
t_3d.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.9, -3, 53));
t_3d.push_back(cv::Point3f(1.45, -3, 53));
t_3d.push_back(cv::Point3f(2, -3, 53));
object_points.push_back(t_3d);

std::vector<cv::Point2f> t_2d;
t_2d.push_back(cv::Point2f(434, 362));
t_2d.push_back(cv::Point2f(570, 362));
t_2d.push_back(cv::Point2f(706, 325));
t_2d.push_back(cv::Point2f(513, 574));
t_2d.push_back(cv::Point2f(513, 574));
t_2d.push_back(cv::Point2f(654, 557));
image_points.push_back(t_2d);

cv::calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, cv::Size(1440, 900), cam_mat,
                    dist_coeffs, rvecs, tvecs, CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS);

cv::Mat tx(4, 1, CV_64F, cv::Scalar(1.0));
tx.at<double>(0, 0) = 0.9;
tx.at<double>(1, 0) = -3;
tx.at<double>(2, 0) = 57.5;

cv::Mat rrr ;
cv::projectPoints(object_points.at(0), rvecs.at(0), tvecs.at(0),cam_mat,
                  dist_coeffs, rrr);
```

I except my `rrr` variable to contain the value of `(434, 362)`, but it gets filled with 6 nonsensical values:

```
rrr = [1.53232e+18, 1.08633e+18, 7.72618e+17, 7.09485e+19, 7.192e+19, 7.26505e+19]
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you get a very a different value, or similar to the expected value?

Comment: can you try `std::vector<cv::Point2f> rrr ;` instead?

Comment: since you deliver 6 points (object_points is a vector with 6 Point2f) it isnt surprising that you get 6 values as a result, but I would've expected a 6x2 or 2x6 matrix, so maybe the Mat is in an unexpected format (maybe each of those 6 values is a 64 bit double which holds both 32 bit values of a point2f)

Comment: using `double a = 1.53232e+18; cv::Point2f * pt = (cv::Point2f*)&a; std::cout << *pt << std::endl;` I get `[nonsens, 362.53]` where the y coordinate is your expected y coordinate, so PROBABLY your mat is just in a format you don't expect. I would really give `std::vector<cv::Point2f> rrr ;` a try ;)

Comment: in fact you are asking for object_points.at(0) which is t_3d, which is a vector of 6 points. try to create a new vector with only 1 point in it and youll get the wanted result.

Comment: about the result values: 451 is "near" the real value, probably an error in your calibration.

Comment: @Micka A vector of size 1 is the cure.